# Inconsistent allocation with RTSStats

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm working on measuring function allocation, and I'm running into some behavior that I don't quite understand. Here's a simple reproduction of it:

```
module Main where

import GHC.Stats (GCDetails(..), RTSStats(..), getRTSStats)
import System.Mem (performGC)

main :: IO ()
main = loop 100
  where
    loop 0 = return ()
    loop n = runOtherThing n >> loop (n-1)

runOtherThing :: Int -> IO ()
runOtherThing n = do
    performGC
    stats <- getRTSStats
    putStrLn $ show (n `mod` 15) ++ ": "
            ++ show (gcdetails_allocated_bytes (gc stats))
            ++ " num: " ++ show (gcs stats)
    --putStrLn "inflate allocation"
```

Which outputs:

```
$ ghc Main.hs
$ ./Main +RTS -s
...
14: 4648 num: 12
13: 4744 num: 13
12: 4744 num: 14
11: 4744 num: 15
10: 4744 num: 16
9: 8704 num: 17
8: 4648 num: 18
7: 4648 num: 19
6: 4648 num: 20
5: 4648 num: 21
4: 4648 num: 22
3: 4648 num: 23
2: 4648 num: 24
1: 4648 num: 25
0: 4648 num: 26
14: 4648 num: 27
13: 4744 num: 28
12: 4744 num: 29
11: 4744 num: 30
10: 4744 num: 31
9: 8704 num: 32
8: 4648 num: 33
7: 4648 num: 34
6: 4648 num: 35
5: 4648 num: 36
4: 4648 num: 37
3: 4648 num: 38
2: 4648 num: 39
1: 4648 num: 40
0: 4648 num: 41
...
```

I'm using 8.2.1 and the new-ish `RTSStats`, but it applies to the old `GCStats` as well.

Every 15 GC's, an extra ~4k bytes (perhaps a page?) are allocated. The number on the left is the loop number `mod` 15 so you don't have to count, just look for the lines that start with `9` in my output. On the right is the total number of GC's performed by the program which shows that we aren't missing data from any.

I've made lots of changes and the number always sticks exactly to 15. You can uncomment the `inflate allocation` line, which does what it says. The extra 4k bytes is still reported. Even if you add multiple lines inflating the allocation it doesn't change.

That makes me believe the extra bytes are independent of my code. Or at the very least, not being triggered by me allocating data.

I don't really know what to make of this. For the purposes of measuring allocation, I could probably develop a reasonable strategy for detecting and removing these data points. But is it possible to avoid this altogether? And what is it about 15?